# How do I change the color of the relief?

Tags: python, tkinter

Initially it is black. But I need a white one.

```
(root, bg='#1e1e1e', fg = '#FFFFFF',
bd = '5',
font = ('Consolas', 20, 'bold'),
justify = 'center',
**relief = 'solid',**
selectbackground = '#FFFFFF',
selectforeground = '#000000',
width = '20'
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [example] of your code, so that we can help you. This question is very unclear, especially since we don't even know what widget you're working with. The answers could be very different depending on whether you're using a `Label`, a `Button`, a `Frame`, etc. See [ask] and the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70056435/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-relief-in-tkinter), you can use `highlightthickness`, `highlightcolor` and `highlightbackground` options to simulate a *white border* for an `Entry` widget:

```py
tk.Entry(root, bg='#1e1e1e', fg = '#FFFFFF',
    bd = '0',  # set no border
    font = ('Consolas', 20, 'bold'),
    justify = 'center',
    selectbackground = '#FFFFFF',
    selectforeground = '#000000',
    # use highlightthickness, highlightcolor and hightlightbackground to simulate white border
    highlightthickness = 5,
    highlightcolor = 'white',
    highlightbackground = 'white',
    width = '20'
).pack()
```